# If I modify a Hibernate entity, after doing a save, when I commit would the changes be saved to the database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

If in Hibernate, I do the following steps:

1. Open a session.
2. Create a new hibernate POJO object (that is to be saved), and fill in the values.
3. Now I do session.save().
4. Now I change the POJO object - say it is an employee object and I do emp.setName("Other Name") i.e change the name of the employee in the object.
5. Now I do a transaction commit.

My question is what would be saved to the database - the name before I did session.save() or the name after the change i.e. "Other Name"?

Comment: Why don't you try it

Answer (score 17):

The moment you saved the entity, it becomes managed and all further changes are propagated to the database during `Session.flush`.

When you saved the entity, you only triggered an `EntityInsertAction` to be queued. After you changed the entity, the current entity state was changed so during a flush, Hibernate will simply insert the latest entity state, so the database will contain the `"Other Name"`.

In fact, calling a method like `save` for a managed entity (which triggers an entity [`merge`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/)) is actually going to affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

While working with managed entity, when you don't call save, it will be saved automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that you´re doing in the session it is commit into the database, once you make transaction commit. Even when you flush your session you´re just adding the changes on the table on memory, but no commit to the database.

So finally once Hibernate detect that the session is dirty, it will commit the change, in case you have automatic dirt check in your configuration, and it will be smart enough to see the last change on your object session. So yeah you will have "Other Name"