# Spring Boot - caling transactional method from non-transactional cause update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, entity

I'm wondering about a case, which I encountered recently. Suppose we have a service method as follows:

```
@Override
public User addUser(UUID organizationId, User user) {
    Organization organization = organizationRepository.findById(organizationId).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    user.setOrganization(organization);
    organization.getUsers().add(user);
    invitationService.deleteByUserEmail(user.getEmail());
    return user;
}
```

Organization is provided by a repository method:

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, UUID> {

    Optional<Organization> findById(UUID id);
}
```

Adding of users works only because `invitationService.deleteByUserEmail(user.getEmail());` is present. The entire method belongs to another service and looks as follows:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteByUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    invitationRepository.deleteByUserEmail(userEmail);
}
```

I am not sure if I correctly understand why adding a user works. According to Hibernate Docs, automatic updates occur only, when an entity is in managed state and the update takes place in a single transaction. If my reasoning is correct there are the following steps which occur:

1. When a request comes and hits the controller, an entity manager (hibernate session) is attached to the current thread. (?)
2. A controller method which handles the request, calls **organizationService.addUser** method
3. **Organization** is fetched by **findById** method which is by default transactional and readonly (according to **SimpleJpaRepository** implementation). This transaction closes after this, but the entity manager bound to it is still running and organization entity remains managed.
4. The updates occur
5. **invitationService.deleteByUserEmail(user.getEmail());** is called. Because it's transactional method a transaction is started. Deletion occurs, and a transaction is committed and flushes all changes into the database, even the changes made in **organization** entity.

Is it possible despite of **addUser** method is **non-transactional**?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955910/if-i-modify-a-hibernate-entity-after-doing-a-save-when-i-commit-would-the-chan

Answer (score 0):

On one of you configuration classes you may have special filters registered which basically keep the session / entitymanager opened for the life of an entire request:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
```

or

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So by default the entity manager has FlushMode.NEVER. Using a @Transactional method somewhere, will set on FlushMode.AUTO and make a flush of all entities changes on transaction commit. Even this ones occured before transaction started. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, AUTO should make the persistence provider flush whenever he feels the need to do so.. for example when some entities are in persistence context and you perform a query which uses some of those entities, then flush will be triggered. IF you want a flush to be always invoked only on transaction commit then use the COMMIT flush mode option